# Is category of associative algebra co-complete?

Tags: abstract-algebra, associativity

Let $R_i$ be a family of associative algebras s.t. $\phi_{ij}:R_i\to R_j$ is unital associative algebra homomorphism where I demand 1 being sent to 1 and I am assuming this is directed limit.

$\textbf{Q:}$ Is $lim R_i$ unital algebra? It seems that I can form limit in the set category first and endow associative algebra structure. In other words, category of associative algebras is co-complete?

$\textbf{Q':}$ Consider $Q$ quiver of infinite size.(i.e. It has infinite vertices . I am going to assume number of arrows between vertices is finite here.) Now approximate $Q$ by subquivers $Q_i$ with $Q_i$ forming ascending filtration of $Q$ where $i$ is the number of vertices. Consider path algebra $KQ_i$. Clearly $K$ is a functor from quiver category to associative algebra(not necessarily unital). So $KQ$ is non unital but each $KQ_i$ has unit. So $K$ does not preserve the direct limit. Am I wrong on this part? The possible place is $K$ being a functor from quiver category to associative algebras rather a functor from finite quiver category to associative algebras.

Comment: Since associative algebras (unital or otherwise) are models of an algebraic theory, the category of associative algebras is complete and cocomplete for abstract nonsense reasons. Limits ("inverse limits") and filtered/directed colimits ("direct limits") are indeed induced by those (co)limits on the underlying sets.

Comment: @DerekElkins Where can I find the exact "abstract nonsense" to fulfill my understanding on this part? Thanks. Reference will be sufficient.

Comment: The theory of [Lawvere theories](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Lawvere+theory) is a good place to start and is enough for this example. From there you can explore related topics like monadicity, algebraic categories, essentially algebraic theories, and even locally finitely presentable categories.

Comment: @DerekElkins Thanks a lot.